# Missing regex results in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently learning Regex in Python and my expected Regex results are not showing (I'm running Python 3.6). Below is the code to get the String values I'm running my regex against:

```
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

url = 'http://www.trumba.com/calendars/brisbane-city-council.json'
uh = requests.get(url)

json_data = json.loads(uh.text)
json_str = json.dumps(json_data)
panda_json = pd.read_json(json_str, typ = 'frame')
```

Now, I want to take a match of the ***html hyperlink*** in 'location'

With the Regex, I'm expecting to find matches such as below (anything between [<] and [>]):

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=33+Teevan+St%2c+Stafford+QLD+4053%2c+Australia" target="_blank">
```

so I'm using below Regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'/[<].*?[>]/')
```

and then try to store them into a dataframe

```
matches = re.findall(pattern, str(panda_json['location']))

x = []
for match in matches:
    x.append(match)

x = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

But 'x' does not show anything? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You are probably looking for `panda_json['location'].str.extract(r'<([^>]+)>')`

Comment: Note that you should really [avoid parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1678362) and that python has the delightful [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library that handles parsing and extracting data from html

Comment: Thanks both! @WiktorStribiżew it works. I will find out the full definition of the regex. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Aaron thanks also for the advice and for pointing to that post. I will dig deeper why we should avoid parsing HTML with regex (although I'm a bit confused.. the solution from Wiktor seems to work)..

Comment: The issue mostly is that HTML is a very permissive language and trying to account for all pitfalls in a regex isn't worth it especially when other tools already do it. Even in your simple case there could (technically, although unlikely) be a `<![CDATA` block or `<!--` comment in these tags that would make the regex fail to parse them whole while a specialized parser would succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply extract the substrings between `<` and `>` using

```
panda_json['location'].str.extract(r'<([^>]+)>')
```

The `<([^>]+)>` pattern  matches `<` with `<`, then matches one or more chars other than `>` with `[^>]+` and - since the pattern is enclosed with `(` and `)` - is placed into Group 1 (and [`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) outputs just the value captured), and then `>` matches a `>` char.